# Sending data through CP2102 receiving weird data

Tags: python, raspberry-pi3, uart

Im trying to connect my raspberry pi 3 B to PC via UART ( Im using CP2102 device),
My Windows 10 recognize this device and raspberry pi can send data but:
'
i tried to write in python commend to send but when i received it look like :

.ţölp~>B|..~Ěr60

then i tried send data using commend:

> sudo echo "ala 11 33" > /dev/ttyS0

but it didn't help.
I was changing the speed on 9600, 115200 etc. but nothing happened.

when Im using:

> sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0

i get:

> speed 115200 baud; line = 0; min = 1; time =0;
> -brkint -icrnl -imaxbel iutf8
> -isig -icanon -iexten -echo -echoe -echok -echoctl -echoke

I don't know what to do. I tried to search information but i failed.

Please help me.

Comment: `sudo` isn't a Windows 10 command.

Comment: How do you _receive_ data?

Comment: Did you try to change the speed at which it is is received? Not just the sending speed...

Comment: Im using "sudo" on raspberry, im receiving data by CoolTerm and i write code in c# for recieving data. Im changing speed(Baudrate) in CoolTerm (and in manager device on pc) and changing in my program in python on raspberry